Image of upper half-plane under sin(z) is not the half strip (Stein and Shakarchi Complex Analysis, Chapter 8)
In section 1.2 of Chapter 8 Conformal Mappings of Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis, it is said that the map $f(z) = \sin(z)$ takes the upper half-plane conformally onto the half-strip $\{w = x + iy : -\pi/2 < x < \pi/2, y > 0\}$. However, I think this is incorrect?
Following their logic, $\sin z = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i} = \frac{-1}{2}\left(i\zeta + \frac{1}{i\zeta}\right)$ where $\zeta = e^{iz}$. This is just the composition of two conformal maps $f(z) = e^{iz}$ and $g(z) = \frac{-1}{2}\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)$. That is, $\sin z = g(f(z))$.
$f$ takes the upper half-plane to the unit disc, and $g$ takes the unit disc to almost all of $\mathbb{C}$ (and in particular certainly much more than just the half strip). Am I missing something or is there an error in this example?
The excerpt from the text is here:


You are correct, there is a mistake. The function $\sin(z)$ maps the half-strip onto the upper-half plane.

In my hardcopy it's the other way around, so the error seems to have been corrected in later printings.
